# Twig error not in dev (windows) but It is there on hosting (Unix)?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm using D8.

I added a field to the user profile:

Lidmaatschapsnummer 
field_lidmaatschapsnummer

On my Windows Aquia desktop this is running good. I now ftp'ed all to my hosting and get the error on url:

/admin/people

> Er is onverwacht een fout opgetreden. Probeer het later nog
>   eens.Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash
>   key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression
>   enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of
>   value "{" in "{# inline_template_start #}<br> {{
>   {{ field_lidmaatschapsnummer }}" at line 1. in Twig_ExpressionParser->parseHashExpression()
>   (line 302 of vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php).
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->parsePrimaryExpression()
>   (Line: 102) Twig_ExpressionParser->getPrimary() (Line: 55)
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->parseExpression() (Line: 149)
>   Twig_Parser->subparse(NULL, ) (Line: 105)

I do not understand how to solve this. The dev is on windows, the hosting on Unix. PHP versions are the same on both.

Any suggestion?

Below is the complete trace:

> Er is onverwacht een fout opgetreden. Probeer het later nog eens.Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in "{# inline_template_start #}<br> {{ {{ field_lidmaatschapsnummer }}" at line 1. in Twig_ExpressionParser->parseHashExpression() (line 302 of vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php). Twig_ExpressionParser->parsePrimaryExpression() (Line: 102)
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->getPrimary() (Line: 55)
>   Twig_ExpressionParser->parseExpression() (Line: 149)
>   Twig_Parser->subparse(NULL, ) (Line: 105)
>   Twig_Parser->parse(Object) (Line: 716)
>   Twig_Environment->parse(Object) (Line: 774)
>   Twig_Environment->compileSource(Object) (Line: 452)
>   Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('{# inline_template_start #} {{ {{ field_lidmaatschapsnummer }}', NULL) (Line: 143)
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment->renderInline('{# inline_template_start #} {{ {{ field_lidmaatschapsnummer }}', Array) (Line: 52)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Element\InlineTemplate::preRenderInlineTemplate(Array)
>   call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 151)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render{closure}() (Line: 582)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 152)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderPlain(Array) (Line: 411)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\PluginBase->viewsTokenReplace(' {{ {{ field_lidmaatschapsnummer }}', Array) (Line: 1347)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase->renderAltered(Array, Array) (Line: 1240)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase->renderText(Array) (Line: 1168)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase->advancedRender(Object) (Line: 226)
>   template_preprocess_views_view_field(Array, 'views_view_field', Array) (Line: 287)
>   Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('views_view_field', Array) (Line: 437)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 1738)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase->theme(Object) (Line: 761)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->elementPreRenderRow(Array)
>   call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 709)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->renderFields(Array) (Line: 576)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->renderGrouping(Array, Array, 1) (Line: 468)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->render(Array) (Line: 2112)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->render() (Line: 1533)
>   Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->render() (Line: 183)
>   Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Page->execute() (Line: 1630)
>   Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('page_1', Array) (Line: 77)
>   Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array)
>   call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}() (Line: 582)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
>   call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
>   Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 666)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an issue(s) in your twig syntax.
The error says

> unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in "{# inline_template_start #}
>  {{ {{ field_lidmaatschapsnummer }}" at line 1.

You may have provided opening parenthesis twice. So, removing one set of opening paranthesis will solve your issue. `{{ field_lidmaatschapsnummer }}`

May this will help you.

Comment: Thxs had indeed a {{ quate too much. Still strange why this is not an issue on my windows machine... anyhow problem solved...

Comment: maybe it has gone into Drupal cache on your local.